# Connect Azure Databricks to SQL Database using a Service Principal and R

Tags: r, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-databricks

In Azure I would like to connect Databricks to an Azure SQL database using using a service principal and R language via Azure Active Directory Autentification.

[Here](https://thedataguy.blog/connect-azure-databricks-to-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-using-a-service-principal/) I learned how to do that using scala. Is there by any means a possibility to do the same using R?

Applying the [AzureAuth](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureAuth/index.html) R-package I was at least able to create a token like that:

```
 get_azure_token(resource = "https://database.windows.net/",
            tenant = "<teneantID>",
            app = "<servicePrincipalID>", 
            password = "<servicePrincipalPW>",
            auth_type = "client_credentials") -> myToken
```

However, I do not see how to continue. The [AzureStor](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AzureStor/index.html) R-package seemingly provides merely the connection to data lakes or blob storages.

So, how can I move on and connect to an Azure SQL from databricks using R?

Comment: Checkout this article: https://thedataguy.blog/connect-azure-databricks-to-sql-database-azure-sql-data-warehouse-using-a-service-principal/ which describes how to connect Azure Databricks to SQL Database using a service principal

Comment: Yes thanks, that article is exactly what I meant with above "Here" link. However, I would like to know how to do so using R (packages) instead of scala (libs).

Comment: Hey, you may try to modify the connect strong with Azure Auth MSDN thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bb3d872-613f-4738-b9d6-bc1dba32a354/unable-to-connect-to-sql-database-using-rodbc?forum=AzureDatabricks

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to be the solution that I am looking for. I will give it a try...

Comment: Have you tried the above sample? Please do let us know.